# FOSRestBundle: rendering XML on browser

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

Let's say I have one REST API call:

```
/api/message/list
```

I want to have different response format depending on HTTP Accept Header.

It works perfect when I request for JSON or XML from curl command. But when I load it from browser, it tries to render twig template and I do NOT want that. I want it returns XML content instead of HTML. With this approach I don't need to create a twig file for browser output.

I want to do this because is practical to have the API output on the browser without need to create a twig for it.

Am I missing something in the configuration file? Or maybe this is not currently supported by default?

I tried using this but doesn't work.

```
fos_rest:
    body_listener:
        decoders:
            html: fos_rest.decoder.xml
            ...
```

My full FOSRest config on config.yml:

```
fos_rest:
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    body_listener:
      decoders:
        json: fos_rest.decoder.json
        xml: fos_rest.decoder.xml
        html: fos_rest.decoder.xml
    format_listener:
      default_priorities: [html, xml, json]
      fallback_format: xml
    view:
        view_response_listener: force
        formats:
            json: true
            xml: true
        force_redirects:
            html: true
        failed_validation: HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
        default_engine: php

sensio_framework_extra:
    view:    { annotations: false }
    router:  { annotations: true }
```

My list action on controller returns just the array of messages:

```
<?php

use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;

class MessageController extends Controller {

    /**
     * @Rest\View()
     */
    public function listAction() {
        $messages = //get the messages
        return $messages;
    }

    ...
}
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: It would be nice to see your routing file.